# Expressão regular start, end

Tags: php, regex

Tenho duas expressões regulares:

```
$exp1 = '/^abc.*\_20150430.txt$/'
$exp2 = '/^def.*\_20150430.txt$/'
```

Deve retornar **true** para arquivos começados por **abc** na primeira e **def** na segunda. As nas duas expressões a string deve terminar por **_20150430.txt**. Para o que preciso devo executar:

```
if(preg_match($exp1, $str) || preg_match($exp2, $str)) {
    // Do something
}
```

Como faço isso em uma única expressão regular?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Você deve usar uma *subpatern* (grupo delimitado com parênteses) com *alternation* (caractere `|` ou *pipe*) conforme [descrito no manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php) (sem tradução).

Dessa maneira a expressão regular fica assim:

`'/^(abc|def).*_20150430\.txt$/'`

Vi que você escapou o *underline* (`\_`), mas esse não é um caractere especial dentro da expressão regular, então não precisa de escape.

O ponto da extensão no nome do arquivo (`430.txt`) deve ser escapado, conforme apontado pelo @wryel, por se tratar de um curinga

Comment: ele deveria escapar . (ponto) após o 20150430 :P

Answer (score 0):

O que poderia ser feito também, e é muito praticado pelos novatos é:

- Formas as diferentes REGEX

  - `/^abc.*_20150430\.txt$/`
  - `/^def.*_20150430\.txt$/`
- uni-las pelo **ou**

  - `^abc.*_20150430\.txt$`**|**`^def.*_20150430\.txt$`

Note que ele interpreta como sendo duas validações distinta, contudo na mesma validação.

Seja funcionando no **[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gM8gL8/1)**

Mas com o tempo se pega as reduções das [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) e os atalhos, assim como na [resposta do @Sanção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60846/express%C3%A3o-regular-start-end/60847#answer-60847).

Comment: Que seria a mesma coisa do que está na pergunta, só que desta vez com expressão regular. É realmente uma forma preguiçosa de novatos.

Comment: @IvanFerrer de falo, mas assim ele já reduz um comando `preg`, e postei assim, pois ja pensei em caso haja mais regex,  com 3, assim como, caso ele queira ter todos os resultados no 3º argumento do `preg_match`, para não fazer duas `regex` e apos um merge.